# How to split a list based on another list of values?

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
some = [["a", "1", "c"], ["a", "2", "@"], ["b", "1", "9"], ["c", "1", "pw"], ["c", "2", "af"]]
```

The list is ordered based on second column. So all rows are sorted here. I am trying the split the list into the n different lists based on unique values. I tried the following

```
import pandas as pd
uniquevals = pd.DataFrame(some)[0].value_counts()
newlist = []
for i in uniquevals:
    newlist = some[1:i]
    print(newlist)
    print("Done\n")
```

and the result is

```
[['a', '2', '@']]
Done

[['a', '2', '@']]
Done

[]
Done
```

But ideally, I want rows in the column to split based on the count of unique values of first column. Here `a` has two values and `b` has one value and `c` has two values. Ideal output should be:

```
[["a", "1", "c"], ["a", "2", "@"]]
Done

[["b", "1", "9"]]
Done

[["c", "1", "pw"], ["c", "2", "af"]]
Done
```

Comment: Are you actually trying to create a DataFrame, or did you just think that Pandas would have the right tools to solve the problem? If you want to treat your data as an ordinary nested list, it is certainly possible to solve the problem cleanly with only the standard library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `pd.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
some = [["a", "1", "c"], ["a", "2", "@"], ["b", "1", "9"], ["c", "1", "pw"], ["c", "2", "af"]]
uniquevals = pd.DataFrame(some)
for _, i in uniquevals.groupby(0):
    print(i.to_numpy().tolist())
    print("Done\n")
```

Output:

```
[['a', '1', 'c'], ['a', '2', '@']]
Done

[['b', '1', '9']]
Done

[['c', '1', 'pw'], ['c', '2', 'af']]
Done
```